# Display push notification in alert box when the app is running in the foreground

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am doing  push notification in my android app that is triggered by GCM. I want to display the notification if the app is running in a alert box,if the app is not running means not in the foreground just display the status bar notification, How do you determine if the app is running and is in the foreground?is this is possible to show notification like this.now am using this code for show status bar push notification

```
  NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

         Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, BottomActivity.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Comment: Just for info, if this is a NEW project you should use GCM instead of C2DM as it's deprecated and Google say"C2DM will accept no new users, and it will grant no new quotas"

Comment: ok thanks,i will use GCM and going to edit my question

Comment: @Jithu i also need to do same in one of my apps, did you find a proper solution and mind posting the same here, it would be a great help thanks.

Comment: Check this out. Simple Solution. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394666/show-push-notifications-when-application-open-closed-in-different-way)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new Activity and theme as it as Dialog and check for foreground activity. Check for below code.

```
         ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningTaskInfo> services = activityManager
                .getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        boolean isActivityFound = false;

        if (services.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName().toString()
                .equalsIgnoreCase(context.getPackageName().toString())) {
            isActivityFound = true;
        }

       if (isActivityFound) {
            resultIntent = new Intent(context, AlertDialogNotification.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_ALERT_MESSAGE_BEAUTIFUL, "anyMessage");
            resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(resultIntent); 
        }
```

In the manifest make the theme as Dialog for the activity. Hope it helps. Let us know if you have issue.

Answer (score 1):

How many activities do you have? If just one, it's quite easy to keep a singleton reference to it between onResume() and onPause() (AKA when it's active), and call the activity from the receiver if it's. if you have many activities, you can achieve a similar logic by having a common base class for them. Something like this:

```
class MyActivity: Activity
{
    static private MyActivity _Current = null;

    protected void onResume() //Activated
    {
        super.onResume();
        _Current = this;
    }

    protected void onPause() //Deactivated
    {
        super.onPause();
        _Current = null;
    }

    //This is for the receiver to call
    static public PopAlert()
    {
        if(_Current != null)
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(_Current)
                .setMessage("Hello world")
                //More alert setup; use _Current as a context object
                .create().show();
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try these

```
public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {

        boolean isInBackground = true;
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
                if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                    for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                        if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName()))
                            isInBackground = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
            ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
            if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                isInBackground = false;
            }
        }
```